# Auto rotation for images not working on flutter app

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, flutter

I am using html and css to display a webview in an iOS app written in swift and an Android app written in Flutter. The image autorotates in browsers and the iOS app but not in the Android app. I would like the images to autorotate to being rightside up using html, css, and/or js. How could I accomplish this? Thanks!

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  
<html>

<style>
#bodystyle {
  position: absolute;
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<body id="bodystyle" style="background-color: #000;">

{%for i in range(images)%}
  
    <img id='image' src="{{ images[i] }}" alt="Image for user"></img>
{%endfor%}
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/c4Rns65. are you looking like this in flutter webview in android

Comment: I don't understand please explain

Comment: the above image was implemented using HTML, CSS in the webview(android) widget. are you looking that like result

Comment: I'm trying to flip images that are rotated 90 degrees upright using EXIF data